# vagrantでrocky linux8にSSHでログインできない

Tags: ssh, vagrant

Windows10にてvagrantでrocky linux8をインストールしたのですがSSHでログインしようとしたところ、下記のエラーが出てしまいログインできませんでした。
なにがいけないのでしょうか。

```
No supproted authentication methods available(server sent:publickey,gssapi-with-mic)
```

以下のような状況です。

①ユーザvagrantは存在している。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

②コマンドプロンプトまではいく。(ここでユーザ名vagrantを入力しEnterするとエラーがでます)
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

③上記のログイン画面でユーザ名vagrantを入力しENTERを押すと下のエラーになります。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

確認のためCentOSを同じくvagrantでインストールしてユーザvagrantでログインしたのですが、特に問題なくログインできました。

Comment: 念の為 Vagrantfile の内容も質問中に含めてみてください。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

まず、Vagrant Box への一般的なログイン方法は、コマンドプロンプトなどで`Vagrant`ファイルのあるディレクトリで

```
vagrant ssh
```

を実行することです。

- 参考: https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/cli/ssh

---

そうではなく、敢えて PuTTY を利用したい場合は:

#### 初期設定手順

1. コマンドプロンプトを起動します。
2. `Vagrant` ファイルのあるディレクトリで `vagrant ssh-config` コマンドを実行し、`User`, `HostName`, `Port`, `IdentityFile` の値をそれぞれ確認します。

   - おそらく `vagrant`, `127.0.0.1`, `2222`, `<Vagrantfileの場所>/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key` になっていると思います
3. `PuTTYgen` を起動します。
4. "Load" で `IdentityFile` のファイルを指定します。

   - ファイル選択ダイアログで拡張子フィルタを `All Files (*.*)` にしないとファイルが見えないので注意
5. "Save privete key" で `.ppk` ファイルを適当な場所に保存します。
6. `PuTTY` を起動します。
7. "**Session**" で、 Hostname, Port 入力欄に、それぞれ上記で確認した値(例: `127.0.0.1`, `2222`)を入力します。
8. "**Connection > Data**" で、 "Auto-login username" に、上記で確認した User 値(例: `vagrant`) を入力します。
9. "**Connection > SSH > Auth**" で、 "Private key file for authentication" 入力欄に、上記で保存した `.ppk` ファイルを指定します。
10. "**Session**" に戻り、"Save Sessions" に適当な名前を入力して "Save" ボタンを押します。

#### ログイン手順

1. 上記で Save した Session を選択して "Load" ボタンを押します。
2. "Open" ボタンを押します。

以上です。

- 参考: [SSH to Vagrant box in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9885108/4506703)

Comment: private-key(`.ppk`)の作成・指定を誤っている、というのが一番あり得そうかなと考えます。